# "Round up to the nearest tertile value" wording question?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, quantifiers

If I wanted to tell someone to round up to the nearest 1/4 value (e.g. 4.78 would become to 5.0), I would say:

> Round up to the nearest quarter value.

Now, if I want to express rounding up to the nearest 1/3 value (e.g. 5.45 would become 5.6666667), would I say:

> Round up to the nearest tertile value.

Is there a specific word to express a 1/3 division, like with how I tried to express in the last statement above?

Comment: Round up to the nearest quarter or quarter decimal. *Tertile* or *tercile* applies to division of some distribution, not necessarily to an interval between consecutive integers.

Comment: Is there a word in the English language that does express this 1/3 interval division?

Comment: What's wrong with, "Round up to the nearest third"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this was a little stupidity on my part. I wasn't thinking.

> Round up to the nearest third [value].

Thanks for the help, Gnawme.

Comment: You perhaps intended to add the above as a _comment_ and _not_ an answer.

Comment: I was simply answering my own question is all. Technically it is the answer to what I was looking for.